# Wildcard for wp-cli search-replace

Tags: wp-cli

I'm trying to perform this search replace:

```
wp search-replace 'http://stage.contraindicaciones.net/app/uploads/2015/{08,09}/' 'http://stage.contraindicaciones.net/app/uploads/2016/03/'
```

But curly brackets {08,09} does not work. I think, because are inside '' and it is rendered as string.

How can I escape the string for this sentence?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried adding `--regex` ?

Comment: How did you go with this @aitor?

Comment: Sorry, Tim, I forgot to comment my final solution and I don't remember what I did (I think, finally, I did not use the curly braces, repeating sentence for each month). I'm afraid this question will remain unsolved this time. I'm sorry.